# Java - BouncyCastle - 3DES encryption and decryption of files: Files are corrupted after round trip

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, 3des

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt files with BouncyCastle 3DES. But the files are corrupted after encrypting and decrypting. For example a simple text-file or a jpg-image-file. This is my Code:

```
ZipUnzipBouncyCastle()
{
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}


public void encrypt3DES(String password, String file)
        throws IOException, DataLengthException, IllegalStateException,
        InvalidCipherTextException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(new File(file).toPath());

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(data);
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
    keyGenerator.init(168, random);
    SecretKey secreteKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
            new CBCBlockCipher(new DESedeEngine()));

    cipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(secreteKey.getEncoded()));

    byte[] result = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
    int tam = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, result, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(result, tam);

    byte[] encodedData = Base64.getEncoder().encode(result);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileOutputStream.write(encodedData);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}

public void decrypt3DES(String password, String file)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, DataLengthException,
        IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException, IOException
{
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(new File(file).toPath());

    byte[] decodedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(decodedData);
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
    keyGenerator.init(168, random);
    SecretKey secreteKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
            new CBCBlockCipher(new DESedeEngine()));

    cipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(secreteKey.getEncoded()));
    byte[] result = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(decodedData.length)];
    int tam = cipher.processBytes(decodedData, 0, decodedData.length, result, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(result, tam);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileOutputStream.write(result);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

I looked all over the Internet but could not find any explanation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you are not doing decryption. You should set first param to false when you do `cipher.init()` in `decrypt3DES()`:

Comment: Plus you're using different keys; please see the first sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES and read the hover text for 'symmetric-key' (or follow it as a link). Plus you aren't setting the IV, and thus for LWAPI implicitly using zeros, which makes your data much less secure, but that's offtopic for SO and already answered many times in cryptography.SX and security.SX where it is ontopic. And after correcting those, getOutputSize isn't exact for decrypt (and can't be) so your output will usually have nulls added. Also you only need to set the provider for JCA, not LWAPI.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. How to set the IV?

Comment: I set the first param in cipher.init() in decrypt3DES() to false. Now I am getting an InvalidCipherTextException pad block corrupted.

Comment: I got the cause: the Bytes written to file are not the same as read from file.